# Key board appears every time when it open the home activity of my app,UNABLE to HIDE KEYBOARD

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have used ACTION BAR and a SEARCH VIEW in it.Every  time i open the slide bar or open home activity it shows the keyboard.
I think it is setting the focus on search View of action bar.But i'm unable to unfocused it.
I tried this code to hide but it dint worked.\

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

And have also tried this
```

Here is the code...

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener , DrawerLayout.DrawerListener,View.OnTouchListener{
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
public SearchView mSearchView;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
String selectedItem;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private MatrixCursor cursor;
private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;
public static Boolean flag = false;
private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;   
MenuItem searchItem;
public static String state;
public static Boolean search_flag; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    search_flag=true;
    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    // Find People
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // Photos
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // Communities, Will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
    // Pages
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));

    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);




    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


    /*final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar,null);
    getActionBar().setCustomView(actionBarLayout);*/
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }



    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
       .detectCustomSlowCalls() 
       .detectDiskReads()
       .detectDiskWrites()
       .detectNetwork()
       .penaltyLog()
       .penaltyFlashScreen() 
       .build());
    try{


       StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
       .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
       .detectLeakedClosableObjects() 
       .setClassInstanceLimit(Class.forName("com.shabdkosh.MainActivity"), 100)
       .penaltyLog()
       .build());}
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    }

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(true);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    mSearchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.search_hint));
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
    ((SearchView) searchItem.getActionView()).setIconified(true);

    mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    mSearchView.setFocusable(false);
    searchItem.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS| MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
    if(search_flag){
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);}
    search_flag=false;
    return true;
}

public void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) 
{
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    mSearchView.setFocusable(false);
    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.Hindi||item.getItemId()==R.id.English||item.getItemId()==R.id.home){
        mSearchView.setFocusable(false);
    }
    //search_flag=true;

    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
            if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
            {
                search_flag=true;
                //return true;
            }
            // Handle action bar actions click
            if(state.equals("home"))
            {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
            case R.id.Hindi:
                if (!Locale.getDefault().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("hi")) 
                {
                    String languageToLoad = "hi"; // language
                    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
                    Locale.setDefault(locale);
                    Configuration config = new Configuration();
                    config.locale = locale;
                    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());


                    Intent in=new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    finish();


                } else 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getString(R.string.hin_sel), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.English:
                if (!Locale.getDefault().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("en"))
                {
                    String languageToLoad = "en"; // language
                    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
                    Locale.setDefault(locale);
                    Configuration config = new Configuration();
                    config.locale = locale;
                    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());


                    Intent in=new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    finish();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getString(R.string.Al_Eng_sel), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        }else if(state.equals("quiz"))
        {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
            case R.id.Hindi:

            if (R.id.Hindi == item.getItemId())

            {
            String languageToLoad = "hi"; // language
            Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new Word_quiz_game()).commit();


            }
            else
            {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getString(R.string.hin_sel), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return true;
            case R.id.English:

            if (R.id.English == item.getItemId())
            {
            String languageToLoad = "en"; // language
            Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;

            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new Word_quiz_game()).commit();

            }
            else
            {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getString(R.string.Al_Eng_sel), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return true;
            default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }


            }

            else if(state.equals("wod"))
            {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
            case R.id.Hindi:

            if (R.id.Hindi == item.getItemId())

            {
            String languageToLoad = "hi"; // language
            Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new WordOFday_More()).commit();


            }
            else
            {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getString(R.string.hin_sel), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return true;
            case R.id.English:

            if (R.id.English == item.getItemId())
            {
            String languageToLoad = "en"; // language
            Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;

            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new WordOFday_More()).commit();

            }
            else
            {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getString(R.string.Al_Eng_sel), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return true;
            default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
            }

            else if(state.equals("browse"))
            {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
            case R.id.Hindi:

            if (R.id.Hindi == item.getItemId())

            {
            String languageToLoad = "hi"; // language
            Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new Browse()).commit();


            }
            else
            {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getString(R.string.hin_sel), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return true;
            case R.id.English:

            if (R.id.English == item.getItemId())
            {
            String languageToLoad = "en"; // language
            Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;

            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new Browse()).commit();

            }
            else
            {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getString(R.string.Al_Eng_sel), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return true;
            default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

            }

            else if(state.equals("his"))
            {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
            case R.id.Hindi:

            if (R.id.Hindi == item.getItemId())

            {
            String languageToLoad = "hi"; // language
            Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new His()).commit();


            }
            else
            {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getString(R.string.hin_sel), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return true;
            case R.id.English:

            if (R.id.English == item.getItemId())
            {
            String languageToLoad = "en"; // language
            Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new His()).commit();

            }
            else
            {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getString(R.string.Al_Eng_sel), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return true;
            default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
            }

            else if(state.equals("fav"))
            {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
            case R.id.Hindi:

            if (R.id.Hindi == item.getItemId())

            {
            String languageToLoad = "hi"; // language
            Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new Fav()).commit();


            }
            else
            {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getString(R.string.hin_sel), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return true;
            case R.id.English:

            if (R.id.English == item.getItemId())
            {
            String languageToLoad = "en"; // language
            Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;

            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new Fav()).commit();

            }
            else
            {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getString(R.string.Al_Eng_sel), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return true;
            default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
            }

            else if(state.equals("qod"))
            {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
            case R.id.Hindi:

            if (R.id.Hindi == item.getItemId())

            {
            String languageToLoad = "hi"; // language
            Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new Qod_more()).commit();


            }
            else
            {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getString(R.string.hin_sel), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return true;
            case R.id.English:

            if (R.id.English == item.getItemId())
            {
            String languageToLoad = "en"; // language
            Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new Qod_more()).commit();

            }
            else
            {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getString(R.string.Al_Eng_sel), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return true;
            default:
            return false;
            }
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

            }

/* *
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    try{
    menu.findItem(R.id.Hindi).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).collapseActionView();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    mSearchView.setFocusable(false);
    hideKeyboard(MainActivity.this);
    getCurrentFocus().clearFocus();
    mDrawerLayout.requestFocus();

    if(state.equals("his")||state.equals("fav")){

    menu.removeItem(R.id.action_search);    
    String lang=Locale.getDefault().toString();
    if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase("en_IN")||lang.equalsIgnoreCase("en_US"))
    {
    menu.removeItem(R.id.English);
    menu.removeItem(R.id.Gujarati);
    menu.removeItem(R.id.Punjabi);
    menu.removeItem(R.id.Bengali);
    menu.removeItem(R.id.Marathi);
    menu.removeItem(R.id.Talugu);
    menu.removeItem(R.id.Tamil);
    menu.removeItem(R.id.Hindi);

    }
    else if(lang.equalsIgnoreCase("hi"))
    {
    menu.removeItem(R.id.Hindi);
    menu.removeItem(R.id.Gujarati);
    menu.removeItem(R.id.Punjabi);
    menu.removeItem(R.id.Bengali);
    menu.removeItem(R.id.Marathi);
    menu.removeItem(R.id.Talugu);
    menu.removeItem(R.id.Tamil);
    menu.removeItem(R.id.English);
    }}

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new Qod_more();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new WordOFday_More();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new His();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new Fav();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new Word_quiz_game();
        break;
    case 6:
        fragment = new Browse();
        break;
    case 7:
        Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this, Settings.class);
        startActivity(in);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager() ;

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String newText) {

    if (newText.length() > 0) {

        try {
            if (newText.length() > 0) {

                if (InternetConnection.isInternetOn(getApplicationContext())) {
                    list = new SearchData().getAutoSuggestion(newText,MainActivity.this);
                } else {
                    list = new SearchDataDB().getAutoSuggestion(newText,MainActivity.this);
                }
            }
            int[] to = { R.id.text_viewdemo };
            String s[] = Arrays.copyOf(list.toArray(),list.toArray().length, String[].class);
            System.out.println("array size :" + s.length);
            String[] columnNames = { "_id", "text" };
            cursor = new MatrixCursor(columnNames);
            String[] array = s; // if strings are in resources
            String[] temp = new String[2];
            int id = 0;
            for (String item : array) {
                temp[0] = Integer.toString(id++);
                temp[1] = item;
                cursor.addRow(temp);
            }
            String[] from = { "text" };
            final CursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.suggest_list, cursor, from, to, 0);
            mSearchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(cursorAdapter);
            mSearchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new OnSuggestionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
                    selectedItem = list.get(position);
                    mSearchView.setQuery(selectedItem, false);
                    if (InternetConnection.isInternetOn(getApplicationContext())) {
                        SearchData_DTO.setSearchData_DTO(new SearchData().getSearched(selectedItem, MainActivity.this));
                    } else {
                        SearchData_DTO.setSearchData_DTO(new SearchDataDB().getSearchedDB(selectedItem, MainActivity.this));
                        }

                    // cursorAdapter.getItem(position).toString();
                    Log.v("search view", selectedItem);                     
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Search.class);
                    i.putExtra("selected", selectedItem);                       
                    startActivity(i);                       
                    flag=true;
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            // mSearchView.onKeyUp(keyCode, event)

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    } else {

        // TO REMOVE LIST WHEN NO TEXT IN SEARCHVIEW

        // mSearchView.onActionViewCollapsed();

        if (list != null) {
            if (list.size() > 0) {
                list.clear();
            }
        }
        // mSearchView.setIconified(true);

        int[] to = { R.id.text_viewdemo };
        String s[] = Arrays.copyOf(list.toArray(), list.toArray().length,String[].class);
        System.out.println("array size :" + s.length);
        String[] columnNames = { "_id", "text" };
        cursor = new MatrixCursor(columnNames);
        String[] array = s; // if strings are in resources
        String[] temp = new String[2];
        int id = 0;
        for (String item : array) {
            temp[0] = Integer.toString(id++);
            temp[1] = item;
            cursor.addRow(temp);
        }
        String[] from = { "text" };

        final CursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.suggest_list, cursor, from, to,0);
        mSearchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        mSearchView.clearFocus();
        mSearchView.setIconified(false);
        mSearchView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mSearchView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mSearchView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    if (InternetConnection.isInternetOn(getApplicationContext())) {
        SearchData_DTO.setSearchData_DTO(new SearchData().getSearched(query, MainActivity.this));
    } else {
        SearchData_DTO.setSearchData_DTO(new SearchDataDB().getSearchedDB(query, MainActivity.this));
    }
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Search.class);
    i.putExtra("selected", query);
    startActivity(i);

    return true;
}


@Override
public void onDrawerClosed(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    hideKeyboard(MainActivity.this);
    mDrawerLayout.requestFocus();
}

@Override
public void onDrawerOpened(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    hideKeyboard(MainActivity.this);
    mDrawerLayout.requestFocus();
}

@Override
public void onDrawerSlide(View arg0, float arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    hideKeyboard(MainActivity.this);
    mDrawerLayout.requestFocus();
}

@Override
public void onDrawerStateChanged(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    hideKeyboard(MainActivity.this);
    mDrawerLayout.requestFocus();
}

public  void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) 
{
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (imm != null && activity != null) {
        View currentFocus = activity.getCurrentFocus();

        if (currentFocus != null) {
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(currentFocus.getWindowToken(), 0);
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        }
    }
    mDrawerLayout.requestFocus();
}


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mDrawerLayout.requestFocus();
    return false;
}

public void setupUI(View view) {

    if(!(view instanceof SearchView)) {

        view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                searchItem.collapseActionView();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    //If a layout container, iterate over children and seed recursion.
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {

        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {

            View innerView = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i);

            setupUI(innerView);
        }
    }

    if(view instanceof DrawerLayout){
        System.out.println("drawer");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please dont get confused by editText,i'm using search view in action bar not editText.And unable to put off the focus of search View,due to which keyboard is getting opened every time.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following method will help

```
searchView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Comment: Still its not working...
I think there is some problem with action bar,as soon as the Name Of the action bar changes,the keyboard appears.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps you out:)

```
public void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for action bar but worth a shot. Add this in manifest on the correct activity : `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`

Comment: Thanks lantonis..
I tried this but it hides first time and again when i get back to my home screen it opens the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

In you onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) add this code,this will unable the keyboard issue

```
mSearchView.setQuery("", false);
```

mSearchView.setIconified(true); 
mSearchView.clearFocus();

Comment: Hey thanks manish this has resoled has resolved the issue...
Keyboard is no longer visible until on tap search view.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <EditText

            <requestFocus /><--Remove this from layout>
  </EditText>
```